# Software/App to explain why police are blaring their sirens

Tags: web-apps

Is there a site or app that will explain why police sirens are running and if there is any specific crime on my local area or zip code? This is specifically for the USA.

I tried a site with police scanners http://www.broadcastify.com/listen/stid/36, but the text updates were only for a fire in a different county that I could not hear. The audio scanner is for the entire county, farther than I can hear. Plus  they speak in code, it's unclear, and realtime, so no history of important things.

Comment: country might be important here... there *may* be a web-app that works in a specific country

Comment: I suspect that a source which lists all police and emergency calls for _the entire USA_ might be a bit too broad in scope. You should try to narrow it to your local region or municipality. Your local incident control center quite possibly hosts a website with real-time events and recent history, but without knowing where you're located, I can't help further.

Comment: Based on the Broadcastify link, the OP seems to live in New York.